# How to use 'docker-compose config' with more than one docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker-compose, dotenv

I am using a `docker-compose.yml` file version 3.x (3.9) and use `.env` files to parse variables into the `docker-compose.yml`.

Docker says that I can use `docker config` to see how the config is used. (here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/config/ )

To create my dev environment I use two files a `dc.yml` and `dc.dev.yml` where the `dc.dev.yml` adds some environment variables.

.env

```sh
A_NEW_VARIABLE=some_new_value
```

dc.yml

```yaml
services:
  api:
    build: .
    environment: 
      - ENV_VARIABLE=old_test
```

dc.dev.yml

```yaml
services:
  api:
    build: .
    environment: 
      - ENV_VARIABLE=${A_NEW_VARIABLE}
```

I regularly spin up with

`docker-compose up --file docker-compose.yml --file docker-compose.dev.yml`

or

`docker-compose up -f ./docker-compose.yml -f ./docker-compose.dev.yml`

BUT when I try to test my config with `docker-compose config` only dc.yml will be picked up and the result is STILL:

```yaml
services:
  api:
    build: .
    environment: 
      - ENV_VARIABLE=old_test # <-- This Value should come from dc.dev.yml
```

I tried to parse the files to the `docker-compose config -f dc.dev.yml`

It seems not possible. Am I right?

Comment: `docker-compose -f dc.dev.yml config` , first -f then config

Comment: Worked! Pls write an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your command to: `docker-compose -f dc.dev.yml config`

First the file you want to check, and then docker command.